# I was able to run ros by "roscore" . But now I am getting an error

Tags: linux, ros

I was able to run ros by "roscore" earlier. But now I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/roscore", line 36, in <module>
    from rosmaster.master_api import NUM_WORKERS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosmaster'
```

How to fix the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused from not sourcing the setup file. Every time you open a new terminal make sure you run `source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash` or make sure that command is added to your `~/.bashrc` file